# MongoDB lookup (join) with field in double nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, join, aggregation-framework, lookup

With a MongoDB collection name `department` with the following structure:

```json
{
  "_id":99,
  "name":"Erick Kalewe",
  "faculty":"Zazio",
  "lecturers":[
    {
      "lecturerID":31,
      "name":"Granny Kinton",
      "email":"gkintonu@answers.com",
      "imparts":[
        {
          "groupID":70,
          "codCourse":99
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "lecturerID":36,
      "name":"Michale Dahmel",
      "email":"mdahmelz@artisteer.com",
      "imparts":[
        {
          "groupID":100,
          "codCourse":60
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and another collection `group` with this structure:

```json
{
  "_id":100,
  "codCourse":11,
  "language":"Romanian",
  "max_students":196,
  "students":[
    {
      "studentID":1
    }
  ],
  "classes":[
    {
      "date":datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 10, 4, 24, 19),
      "cod_classroom":100
    }
  ]
}
```

join them to get the following:

```json
{
  "_id":99,
  "name":"Erick Kalewe",
  "faculty":"Zazio",
  "lecturers":[
    {
      "lecturerID":31,
      "name":"Granny Kinton",
      "email":"gkintonu@answers.com",
      "imparts":[
        {
          "groupID":70,
          "codCourse":99
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "lecturerID":36,
      "name":"Michale Dahmel",
      "email":"mdahmelz@artisteer.com",
      "imparts":[
        {
          "_id":100,
          "codCourse":11,
          "language":"Romanian",
          "max_students":196,
          "students":[
            {
              "studentID":1
            }
          ],
          "classes":[
            {
              "date":datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 10, 4, 24, 19),
              "cod_classroom":100
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The objective is to get a report with the number of students taught by a professor from a department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- unwind, do the join, and re-group back
- its kinda big query because you want to join in nested field, and this means 2 unwind and 2 groupings to restore the structure
  (i think in general joining fields shouldn't go deep inside)
- unwind both arrays
- do the lookup on groupID
- and now construct back the document as 2 level nested
- first its impacts that need to be grouped and pushed
  (for rest argument i keep the $first)
  we sum also the students based on the comment
- then its lecturers that i need to be grouped and pushed
  (for rest arguments i keep the $first)
  we take the lecture with the max students in the department
  (mongodb can compare documents also)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62a4b5d691b564fc1e7e95a2) (you can put your mouse at the end of each stage to see `in/out` of that stage)

```js
department.aggregate(
[{"$unwind": "$lecturers"}, {"$unwind": "$lecturers.imparts"},
 {"$lookup": 
   {"from": "coll",
    "localField": "lecturers.imparts.groupID",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "lecturers.imparts"}},
 {"$set": {"lecturers.imparts": {"$first": "$lecturers.imparts"}}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": {"_id": "$_id", "lecturersID": "$lecturers.lecturerID"},
    "name": {"$first": "$name"},
    "faculty": {"$first": "$faculty"},
    "lecturers": 
     {"$first": 
       {"lecturerID": "$lecturers.lecturerID",
        "name": "$lecturers.name",
        "email": "$lecturers.email"}},
    "imparts": {"$push": "$lecturers.imparts"},
    "lecture_max_students": 
     {"$sum": "$lecturers.imparts.max_students"}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"lecturers": 
     {"$mergeObjects": 
       ["$lecturers", {"imparts": "$imparts"},
         {"lecture_max_students": "$lecture_max_students"}]},
    "imparts": "$$REMOVE","lecture_max_students": "$$REMOVE"}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": "$_id._id",
    "name": {"$first": "$name"},
    "faculty": {"$first": "$faculty"},
    "lectures": {"$push": "$lecturers"},
    "dept-max-lecturer": 
     {"$max": {"max-students": "$lecturers.lecture_max_students",
               "lecturerID": "$lecturers.lecturerID"}}}}])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! One more question: having that is there anyway to obtain the lecturer with the maximum number of students for each department?  So I would have to count the number of students a lecturer imparts class to and the find the maximum across all lecturers from the department. It would be ideal if it could be done within the same "code sentence as the one above but if it not possible it is great too. I am quite new to mongodb and this way over my capacitites

Comment: i updated it to do both, i think its ok

Comment: Wow and people call SQL difficult. This is unreadable, with random dollar signs in most (but not all?) places and curly braces that try to imitate LISP.

Comment: @Endrju if you click on the link, on the right side you see the same in cMQL a query language that i made to avoid the JSON, and it looks like Clojure, MongoDB with JSON allows us to create query builders, see cmql.org what i did, query builders are made in many language so dont let JSON drive you away, it can be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this cMQL just basically replaced dollars with colons. I think I'll migrate my stuff back to relational db and forget about this thing.

Comment: Its the JSON, JSON allows less collections, higher level data(close to real world objects), and its fast avoiding joins especially in distributed databases. If you try JSON in sql, you will get even more complicated query than the above. So i think the question is tables or json? and if the answer to this is mainly tables then i think you need relational database.

Answer (score 2):

You can try aggregation framework,

- `$lookup` with `group` collection pass `lecturers.imparts.groupID` as `localField` and pass `_id` as `foreignField`
- `$addFields` to merge `group` data with `imports` and remove `group` fields because it is not needed
- `$map` to iterate loop of `lecturers` array
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object of `lecturers` and updated object of `imports`
- `$map` to iterate loop of `imports` array
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object of `imports` and found result from `group`
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `group` array and find the group by `groupID`
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from above filtered result

```
db.department.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "group",
      localField: "lecturers.imparts.groupID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "group"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      lecturers: {
        $map: {
          input: "$lecturers",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                imparts: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$this.imparts",
                    as: "i",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$i",
                        {
                          $arrayElemAt: [
                            {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$group",
                                cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$i.groupID"] }
                              }
                            },
                            0
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      group: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g8wGIHMiqJw)

Answer (score 0):

Now that we understand the question (according to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72582827/mongodb-find-maximum/72582923#72584311)), an answer can be:

1. Add each `department` document a set of all its relevant groups.
2. `$lookup` only the student ids for each group to create a `groups` array.
3. Insert the relevant `groups` data to each `lecturer`.
4. Calculate `maxImpartsStudents` which is the number of unique students per `lecturer` from all of its `groups`
5. `$reduce` the `lecturers` array to include only the `lecturer` with highest `maxImpartsStudents`.
6. Format the answer

```
db.department.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      groups: {
        $setIntersection: [
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$lecturers.imparts.groupID",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "group",
      let: {groupIDs: "$groups"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$in: ["$_id", "$$groupIDs"]}}},
        {
          $project: {
            students: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$students",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this.studentID"]]}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "groups"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      lecturers: {
        $map: {
          input: "$lecturers",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {lecturerID: "$$this.lecturerID"},
              {groups: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$this.imparts",
                    in: {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$groups",
                        {$indexOfArray: ["$groups._id", "$$this.groupID"]}
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      lecturers: {
        $map: {
          input: "$lecturers",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                maxImpartsStudents: {
                  $size: {
                    $reduce: {
                      input: "$$item.groups",
                      initialValue: [],
                      in: {$setUnion: ["$$value", "$$this.students"]}
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {lecturerID: "$$item.lecturerID"}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      lecturers: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$lecturers",
          initialValue: {
            "maxImpartsStudents": 0
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {$gte: ["$$this.maxImpartsStudents", "$$value.maxImpartsStudents"]},
              "$$this", "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      lecturerID: "$lecturers.lecturerID",
      maxImpartsStudents: "$lecturers.maxImpartsStudents",
      departmentName: "$name"
    }
  }
])
```

Which is much better than combining the solutions from both questions.

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yJ0-I5Y64db)