# MOngoDB find maximum

Tags: arrays, mongodb, count, max

Good Morning:

I have the following MongoDB structure:

```
  {
    "_id": 19,
    "name": "Fredia Donan",
    "faculty": "Zoomzone",
    "lectures": [
      {
        "lecturerID": 25,
        "name": "Sigismondo Brecknell",
        "email": "sbrecknello@pinterest.com",
        "imparts": [
          {
            "_id": 76,
            "codCourse": 23,
            "language": "Malay",
            "max_students": 59,
            "students": [
              {
                "studentID": 25
              }
            ],
            "classes": [
              {
                "date": ISODate("2022-02-02T09:23:32.59"),
                "cod_classroom": 76
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Having that I want to find the lecturer that imparts class to the maximum number of students. So I have to count the number of students that a lecturer teaches to and the find the max from across all lecturers from the department. How could I do it? Can it be done within the same code of the aggregation bellow? It is way over my MongoDB knowledge and I would be forever grateful if anyone could help.

I have read about $size and $count but everywhere I try it gives me different errors.

Thank you very much in advance!

The output above is done by an aggregation of two collections **department** and **group** with the following  code:

```
            [{"$unwind": "$lecturers"}, {"$unwind": "$lecturers.imparts"},
            {"$lookup": 
            {"from": "group",
                "localField": "lecturers.imparts.groupID",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "lecturers.imparts"}},
            {"$group": 
            {"_id": {"_id": "$_id", "lecturersID": "$lecturers.lecturerID"},
                "name": {"$first": "$name"},
                "faculty": {"$first": "$faculty"},
                "lecturers": 
                {"$first": 
                {"lecturerID": "$lecturers.lecturerID",
                    "name": "$lecturers.name",
                    "email": "$lecturers.email"}},
                "imparts": {"$push": "$lecturers.imparts"}}},
            {"$set": 
            {"lecturers": 
                {"$mergeObjects": 
                ["$lecturers",
                    {"imparts": 
                    {"$reduce": 
                        {"input": "$imparts",
                        "initialValue": [],
                        "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}]},
                "imparts": "$$REMOVE"}},
            {"$group": 
            {"_id": "$_id._id",
                "name": {"$first": "$name"},
                "faculty": {"$first": "$faculty"},
                "lectures": {"$push": "$lecturers"}}}])
```

My desired output would be to get the lecturer of each department that teaches the most students. For instance, if I have this:

```
  {
    "_id": 19,
    "name": "Fredia Donan",
    "faculty": "Zoomzone",
    "lectures": [
      {
        "lecturerID": 25,
        "name": "Sigismondo Brecknell",
        "email": "sbrecknello@pinterest.com",
        "imparts": [
          {
            "_id": 76,
            "codCourse": 23,
            "language": "Malay",
            "max_students": 59,
            "students": [
              {
                "studentID": 25
              }
            ],
            "classes": [
              {
                "date": ISODate("2022-02-09T23:32:59.000Z"),
                "cod_classroom": 76
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "_id": 77,
            "codCourse": 24,
            "language": "Malayff",
            "max_students": 59,
            "students": [
              {
                "studentID": 28
              }
            ],
            "classes": [
              {
                "date": ISODate("2022-02-09T23:32:59.000Z"),
                "cod_classroom": 77
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "lecturerID": 36,
        "name": "Sigismondo Brecknell",
        "email": "sbrecknello@pinterest.com",
        "imparts": [
          {
            "_id": 76,
            "codCourse": 23,
            "language": "Malay",
            "max_students": 59,
            "students": [
              {
                "studentID": 45
              }
            ],
            "classes": [
              {
                "date": ISODate("2022-02-09T23:32:59.000Z"),
                "cod_classroom": 76
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "_id": 77,
            "codCourse": 24,
            "language": "Malayff",
            "max_students": 59,
            "students": [
              {
                "studentID": 54
              },
              {
                "studentID": 435
              },
              {
                "studentID": 45
              }
            ],
            "classes": [
              {
                "date": ISODate("2022-02-09T23:32:59.000Z"),
                "cod_classroom": 77
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to get that for the department with _id 19 the lecturer that teaches the most students is the one with id 36 since he imparts class to 4 students while the lecturer with id 25 imparts class to only 2 students.

So I would like to get the following output:

```
    "_id": 19,
    "name": "Fredia Donan",
    "lecturerID": 36,
    "maxImpartsStudents": 4
   }
```

And I would like to get this information for every existing department. Every document in the collection **department**

Comment: I updated the answer, but it seems your expected output is not according to your sample data. On your sample data `"lecturerID": 36` has only 3 unique students

Comment: Also, did you wrote all the stages in the aggregation pipeline on your question just to get the input for the question? It seems like there is a lot of redundancy there. Too many `$unwind` and `$group`. You could get your expected outcome for the stages there...

Comment: When I add to the aggregation that I first had, the code you sent I do not get the maxImpartsStudents. {'_id': 34, 'lecturerID': 94, 'name': 'Merell Ivanshintsev'}
I get this but no maxImpartsStudents. I have added the code to the first aggregation of the question

Comment: This is because I'm not using your aggregation. I'm using the input that you publish. I can't use your aggregation since I don't have the input for it

Comment: If it doesn't work, then the input you provided is not matching your aggregation

Comment: On stackOverflow, when you ask a question you provide an input data and a requested output from this data. Your aggregation is not useful to answer the question as it has no input data, thus I used the input data that you provided, which is probably after your aggregation.

Comment: Since your question is split to two questions, please check out single solution to both: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72576425/mongodb-lookup-join-with-field-in-double-nested-array/72584497#72576425

Comment: i updated my answer to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72576425/mongodb-lookup-join-with-field-in-double-nested-array) i think its best to be there, because those 2 questions are about the same query, maybe delete this, and update the old question to ask for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Cristina Aranda!

**EDIT**:

1. For each `lecturer`, iterate all `imparts` using `$map` and creates one set that includes all students, returning its size as `maxImpartsStudents`. We use `$setUnion` to avoid counting the same student more than once, if they are in more than one class of the same lecturer.
2. `$reduce` the `lecturers` in each document to include only the one with maximal value of `maxImpartsStudents` .
3. Format

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      lectures: {
        $map: {
          input: "$lectures",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                maxImpartsStudents: {
                  $size: {
                    $reduce: {
                      input: "$$item.imparts",
                      initialValue: [],
                      in: {$setUnion: ["$$value", "$$this.students"]}
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                name: "$$item.name",
                lecturerID: "$$item.lecturerID"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      lectures: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$lectures",
          initialValue: {maxImpartsStudents: 0},
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {$gte: ["$$this.maxImpartsStudents", "$$value.maxImpartsStudents"]},
              "$$this", "$$value"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      lecturerID: "$lectures.lecturerID",
      maxImpartsStudents: "$lectures.maxImpartsStudents",
      departmentName: "$name"
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GJc68daLiS_)

Comment: Hi! For what I have tried this shows the field MaxImpartsStudents as the number of total students taught by professor of the same department but I would like that number to be of each lecturer.

Comment: And I only get as a result what I guess is the department with most students but I would like to get the lecturer of each department with most students

Comment: I updated the answer to return the lecturer document per `faculty`. There is no `department` in the data. I suggest you will edit the question and add the expected output to the sample data you publish

Comment: I am sorry I haven explained myself right. The proposed answer is almost right but I still haven't put it clear. I will update the question with my desired output if you could look at it one more time. Again, very sorry for the misunderstanding.